# ARM : LPC2148 Registers and programming examples

Tags: arm, microcontroller

I am a beginner in using ARM LPC2148 MCU for project purpose. I searched for details about tutorials, example set, registers details of MCU but could not find much.

Please let me know site that would be useful for me to avail the datasheet, examples and functionalities of LPC2148 ARM MCU

Comment: do you have an eval board in mind or just raw parts?

Comment: I just put "LPC2148" into a search engine and the very first result was the Keil site with links to the datasheet, manual, example code, application notes, pretty much everything. How hard did you look?

Comment: I did but none of the sites contained any kind of document / content for like beginners to advance level

Comment: No I am using Proteus

Comment: all of the register details are easy to find if you go to the nxp website, simply search for lpc2148.  geez. the first google hit I get is the datasheet, the second hit is the users manual with all of the registers described...

Comment: Since you paid for Proteus just call their tech support and/or use their examples.